# SVG in Canvas using fabric js and FileReader API

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs, filereader

i try to reader **SVG** in Canvas using **fabric js** and **File Reader API**

the following code for Image and it will work with SVG but it will not use full functionality like change color (*setFill*) and other which work only for SVGs

```js
var reader = new FileReader(), input = document.getElementById('imgFile');
      
      reader.onload = function (event) {
       //loadSVGFromString
        var imgObj = new Image();
        imgObj.src = event.target.result;
        imgObj.onload = function () {
            // start fabricJS stuff
            var coord = getRandomLeftTop();
            var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
            if($scope.ImgOption != 'bg'){
             image.set({
                 left: coord.left,
                 top: coord.top
             });
             canvas.add(image);
            }else{
             image.set({
              scaleY: canvas.height / imgObj.height,
                  scaleX: canvas.width / imgObj.width
             });
             canvas.setBackgroundImage(image, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
            }
            // end fabricJS stuff
         }
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fix this issue by check type of file if it svg i use **loadSVGFromString** method to render object as svg path and color it

```
function reader(e){
      var FileType='';
      if(!window.FileReader && !window.File && !window.FileList && !window.Blob){
         var IEversion = detectIE();
         if (IEversion !== false) {
            if(IEversion == 9 || IEversion == 8) {
               alertify.alert("You're useing IE v"+IEversion+", /n Pleaase upgrade IE to v10 or higher in order to use the app features!"); // in html5 works and fires alert but not in IE8 
            }
         }
         return;
      }
        var reader = new FileReader(), input = document.getElementById('imgFile');

      reader.onload = function (event) {

       var coord = getRandomLeftTop();
        if(FileType == 'svg'){
            fabric.loadSVGFromString(event.target.result, function(objects, options) {
                 var loadedObject = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
                 loadedObject.set({
                    left: coord.left,
                    top: coord.top
                 }).setCoords();
                 canvas.add(loadedObject);
              });
        }else{
            var imgObj = new Image();
            imgObj.src = event.target.result;
            imgObj.onload = function () {
                // start fabricJS stuff
                var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
                   if($scope.ImgOption != 'bg'){
                    image.set({
                        left: coord.left,
                        top: coord.top
                    });
                    canvas.add(image);
                }else{
                    image.set({
                        scaleY: canvas.height / imgObj.height,
                      scaleX: canvas.width / imgObj.width
                    });
                    canvas.setBackgroundImage(image, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
                }
                // end fabricJS stuff
             }
          }
      }

      if (!input) {
         alertify.alert("Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
      } else if (!input.files) {
         alertify.alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
      } else if (!input.files[0]) {
         alertify.alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
      } else {
         file = input.files[0];
         if (file.type == 'image/svg+xml') {
             FileType = 'svg';
             reader.readAsText(file);//readAsText(file);
         }else{
               FileType = 'image';
               reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         }
      }
    }
```